# How do I persist the button color after favoriting in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-environment, swiftui-button

I would like my favorites button to switch colors based on if the user favorites or unfavorites a character. I am able to change the text from "Favorite" to "Favorited" and change the color initially. If I exit the app, the button color goes back to the original color. I have logic in my computed property for the color to change but don't know how to persist it when the user open and closes the app.

Here is my code.

```
import SwiftUI

struct CharacterDetailsView: View {
    
   
 var character: Character
    
    @EnvironmentObject var favorites: Favorites
   
    
    @State private var isFavorited = false
  
    
    
    var favoriteText: String {
        if isFavorited  {
            return "Favorited"
        } else {
            return "Favorite"
        }
    }
    
    var favoriteButton: some View {
        Button {
            isFavorited.toggle()
           
            
            if favorites.contains(character) {
                //If favorites contains a character, we are trying to un-favorite and remove it
                favorites.remove(character)
            } else {
                favorites.add(character)
            }
           
        } label: {
            ZStack {
                if isFavorited == false {
                    Capsule()
                        .strokeBorder(Color.green, lineWidth: 4)
                        .frame(width: 250, height: 50)
                        .background(
                            Capsule()
                                .fill(.green)
                                .cornerRadius(20)
                        )
                
                } else {
                    Capsule()
                        .strokeBorder(Color.blue, lineWidth: 4)
                        .frame(width: 250, height: 50)
                        .background(
                        Capsule()
                            .fill(.blue)
                            .cornerRadius(20)
                        )
                        
                }
                
                HStack {
                    Text(favoriteText)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                    Image(systemName: favorites.contains(character) ? "heart.fill" : "heart")
                        .foregroundColor(favorites.contains(character) ? .white : .white)
                        
                }
            }
        }
        .padding(.vertical)
    }
 
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                //MARK: - Image
                AsyncImage(url: URL(string: character.image)) {
                    phase in
                    if let image = phase.image {
                        image
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                    } else if phase.error != nil {
                        Text("Couldn't upload photo")
                    } else {
                        ProgressView()
                    }
                }
            

                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(character.name)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .bold()
                        .padding(.leading)
                       
                    

            favoriteButton
    
            }
        }
       
    }
    
    
  
}
```

Comment: When you come back to a view and it’s redrawn, the properties get reinitialized. Your state goes back to false. Need to persist the state on disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to restore state from environment object where you stored provious one, like

```
favoriteButton
   .onAppear {
      isFavorite = favorites.contains(character)    // << here !!
   }
```